# What would you call the different subdivisions of a college?

Tags: difference, word-difference

Department, division, section and branch confuse me at times. What would you call the different subdivisions of a college? Suppose I studied at a college that goes by *Faculty of Languages and Translation*. The college has "different areas of study", would you call them departments or divisions? A department (or division) has, in turn, subdivisions, would you call these subdivisions branches or sections?:

> Faculty of Languages and Translation, English Language department, Simultaneous Interpretation section.

And how can I properly mention my university degree in speech?

> **Speech:** I have a bachelor's degree in simultaneous interpretation from the Faculty of Languages and Translation, Alexandria University.

Answer (score 2):

These are part of the names that the college gives to its parts. So don't expect all colleges to be the same.

Generally, a "Faculty" is bigger than a "Department", the context would often make this clear. If you say "The interpretation division of the French department" we know that the "division" is smaller than a department.  On the other hand, if you said "The French department of the Languages division" we know that your college uses "division" to mean something larger than a department. Just use whatever language the college already uses.

When referring to your degree, it is normal just to mention the college and the subject: "An English Degree from Oxford". There is no need to mention the faculty or department.